# JPA entity mapping issue: all fields mapped as null after introducing new field in entity class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

why all fields in a JPA entity are mapped as null after introducing a new field, and the size of an ArrayList is correct but all elements are null?

any thoughts on this issue?

```
@Entity
@IDClass(YourEntity.class)
@Table(name = "your_table")
public class YourEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = true) //
    private String existingField;

    @Column(nullable = true) //
    private String newField;

}
```

repository class

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.Tuple;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface YourEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long> {

    List<Tuple> findByIDIgnoreCase(String type, String method);
}
```

service class

```
List<Tuple> result = yourRepository.findByIDIgnoreCase(type, method);
```

Comment: Provide the code that you have, without it we can’t help you.

Comment: added code, and have jpa class , just find by method. which is called from other service class , returning a list of values, that is list of rows

Comment: I guess the problem is in the query that you provide.

Comment: I let hibernate jpa generate the query when I compared the old and new query in the logs. a new query having a new filed. that's the only difference in the query